# Please help me debug my Insertion Sort Program

Tags: c, debugging, insertion-sort

I can't figure out what is going wrong with it.

If input: 4,56,5,2  then output shown is: 2,4,0,1304.

If input: 27,54,43,26,2  then output shown is: 2,26,0,1304,0

If input: 34,87,54,4,34    then output shown is: 4,34,0,1304,0

Basically, only first two sorted nos are being shown in output and on other places either 1304 or 0 is showing for any set of input.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a[10],b[10];
  int i,size,j,k;
  clrscr();
  printf("please tell how many nos you want to enter");
  scanf("%d",&size);
  printf("Enter the nos");
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  b[0]=a[0];
  //insertionSort algo ---->
  for (j=1;j<size;j++)
  {
    for (k=j-1;k>=0;k--)
      //handling comparision with b[0]
      if (k==0&&(a[j]<b[0])) {
        b[1]=b[0];
        b[0]=a[j];
      }
    //handling comparison with b[1:size-1]
    if (k>0&&(a[j]<b[k]))   { b[k+1]=b[k]; }
    if (k>=0&&(a[j]>=b[k])) { b[k+1]=b[k]; break; }
  }
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)  printf("%d\n",b[i]);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Expected result is the numbers which were input to be displayed in a sorted ascending order

Comment: Logic is extremely flawed. Get out a piece of paper, draw out how you think this program should work. It seems like you started coding without first understanding the program.

Comment: @Mannimacro-I am doing the same for a week but its not helping ;)

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using two arrays, insertion sort can be done in place. There is a good description with pseudocode on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Answer (score 0):

Use a algorithm that's more simple:

1. After reading the numbers, copy array A to B to keep the original input.
2. For ascending sort, set i = 0, j = i + 1
3. loop j until end of array, if B[j] < B[i] then exchange the two numbers.
4. Increase i, set j = i + 1, go to step 3. unless i >= size.
5. print arrays A and B

The algorithm can be optimized later.

Comment: while yours is a sorting algorithm but its not Insertion sort in specific.In insertion sort,you add another no to a sorted list in such a way theat the resulting is list is also sorted.For ex: Insertion sort is used in sorting playing cards.

Comment: Indeed, for that I'd prefer a linked list then instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the minimal changes with `/* comments */` to make your program work:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a[10],b[10];
  int i,size,j,k;
  clrscr();
  printf("please tell how many nos you want to enter");
  scanf("%d",&size);
  printf("Enter the nos");
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  b[0]=a[0];
  //insertionSort algo ---->
  for (j=1;j<size;j++)
    for (k=j-1;k>=0;k--)
    { /* the inner loop must contain all the if statements */
      //handling comparision with b[0]
      if (k==0&&(a[j]<b[0])) {
        b[1]=b[0];
        b[0]=a[j];
        break;  /* done; don't mess with b[0+1] below */
      }
      //handling comparison with b[1:size-1]
      if (k>0&&(a[j]<b[k]))   { b[k+1]=b[k]; }
      if (k>=0&&(a[j]>=b[k])) { b[k+1]=a[j]; break; }  /* =a[j] */
    }
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)  printf("%d\n",b[i]);
  getch();
}
```